# Deleting array of objects server side from restkit

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, curl, restkit

I'm trying to delete several playlists objects from my server at once, but I can't find a way to do this with restkit. I'm basically trying to recreate this curl function:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: DELETE" -d "{\"playlists\":{\"array\":[ {\"id\":\"25\"}, {\"id\":\"26\"},{\"id\":\"22\"},{\"id\":\"23\"},{\"id\":\"24\"}]}}" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/5/playlists
```

Is this possible with restkit?

Comment: Are you using object mapping? Have you tried something like this:https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Posting-Data-Objects?

Comment: This delete:usingBlock: method might also be helpful: http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKClient.html#//api/name/delete:usingBlock:

Comment: SO freaked out and wouldn't let me edit: that above link is meant to point to delete:usingBlock:.

Comment: I am using object mapping and am able to post objects. I know I could just post objects to my rails delete method and have it work that way, but I was hoping their was a cleaner way to delete multiple objects. What's the link you were trying to share?